# jQuery UI autocomplete - results not shown when input does not match resultset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

#### Short version of Problem

Autocomplete works when the input string matches the result string, but not otherwise. The data are succesfully retreived from JSON.

#### Longer version

I want to dynamicly edit the source content of the autocomplete with JSON data.

The approach below works when the search string matches the first_name and last_name field.

But the JSON url returns more, e.g. with search on username it still returns correct data. But this is not shown in autocomplete, and *my theory is that autocomplete UI forces the 'input value' to be the same as the 'result value'*.

#### JSON data returns:

```
[
        {"pk": 1012912, "fields": {"first_name": "Barack", "last_name": "Obama"}}, 
        {"pk": 1017519, "fields": {"first_name": "George", "last_name": "Bush"}}
]
```

#### The autocomplete code

As you can see the result set is set by the search function.

---

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: [],
    search: function(event, ui){
        results = [];
        var json = jQuery.getJSON('http://jsondata.com?query='+event.target.value, function(data){
            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                results.push(data[i].fields.first_name + ' ' +data[i].fields.last_name); 
            };
        }).success(function(){
            $('#search').autocomplete('option', 'source', results);
            //The following debug proves that the 'results' are correct, even on search for usernames
            console.log(results);
        });
    },
});
```

If I search for 'Barack Obama' in the #search field, I get my results, no problem. 
However, if say Barack Obama had the username 'baracko' and I search for his username, then I get the correct results from the JSON and in the results array (as I checked this with console.log) but the results are not shown.

Anyone have the idea why?

### Solution for future googlers or those intrested

Thanks to some hints by ek_ny here is my new JSON:

```
[{ 'value' : 'Barack Obama'}, { 'value' : 'George Bush'}]
```

And here is the code:

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, res){
        jQuery.getJSON('http://jsondata.com/?query='+req.term, req, function(data){  
            var results = [];
            $.each(data, function(i, val){
                results.push(val.value)
            });
            //Add results to callback       
            res(results);
        });           
    },
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but I set up my autocomplete a bit differently. I use the source property which allows me to control the call back to jQuery. My ajax call returns items in the form of [{"id":1, "label": "Annie Hall",.....]. You could modify the results of the Ajax call however you want depending on how the data comes back from the server. Here is the code I use to call it.

```
        $("#movieSearch").autocomplete({
            source: function(req, res){
                $.getJSON(
                    "search.aspx",
                    {term : req.term},
                    function(data){
                        res(data);//you can also modify your results before you call res()
                    }
                );
            }
);
```

One thing in your example which troubles me is the variable results, which seems to me to be a global variable. And we all know (in the words of Douglas Crockford) that global variable are evil.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 


As I have understood it, if you use the JSON in source: then it must return the data with "label": in the JSON?
Currently I'm using Django, and it outputs "fields" - so I'll have to change that, but thats another problem :) 


Regarding the global variable: 
Would it be better to put the results = [] inside the getJSON?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you detect when there is no result

```
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.getJSON( url, {
        term: extractLast( request.term )
    }, response )
    .error(function() {
        console.log("no results");
    });
},
```